# How To: Refresh environment A(QA) from environment B(Prod) after they're out of sync

Tags: sql-database, sim, content-migration

I'm sure you've been in this spot. Client has a QA and a Prod environment, but over time they stopped using best practices, and they have only been authoring content/template changes in Prod, nothing in QA.

Sitecore version 8.2.

### I want QA to match Prod in preparation for a large project.

### What's the approach to get QA to match Prod?

- Is it generally just copy the DB's and that's it for all Sitecore content/templates/config?
- What DB's should I move over to QA? All of them? Any gotchas after moving the DB's?
- Any hope for moving over PDF's/images/other media to QA that were only uploaded and used in Prod thus-far? (I assume media files are NOT stored in the DB, but don't know how to verify)
- Any hope for moving over custom code to QA (since Prod has had different code deployed to it over time)?

Comment: Sitecore Sidekick

Comment: @MarkCassidy - I'm not familiar with `Sitecore Sidekick`. I think it'd be great if you posted an answer with a little more info/notes on what `Sitecore Sidekick` gives you with respect to this question (i.e. which/all of my bullets does it help with?). ---- it will help everyone if someone like yourself who's already familiar with it posts key important info about it, so others can benefit from your existing familiarity with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we need to do this type of content refresh, we generally follow the below steps:

1. Backup the PROD and QA `master` databases.
2. Restore a backup of the PROD `master` database into the QA database server.

   - Note: you may need to stop the AppPool for your CM environment to perform this restore.
3. Deploy the latest code and developer-controlled Sitecore items to the QA environment.

   - Note: in our case, there are typically newer items in QA because it's farther ahead in the development pipeline. Things like template changes, settings changes, new base folders, etc. Those items will need to be added back into QA after restoring from PROD.
4. If your deployment process does not cause the application to restart, clear the Sitecore cache:

   - `https://sitecore-server/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx`
5. Update any QA-specific Sitecore items. Some potential examples:

   - Publishing targets and their database names
   - External connector settings items (e.g. modules)
6. Publish the `/sitecore` item with subitems to all publishing targets
7. Rebuild all content-based search indexes (you can probably safely skip the `sitecore_core_index`)
8. Rebuild the links databases

Regarding your other questions:

1. Copying the `master` database will cover all the content. If you need security or other Sitecore application configuration changes, you may want to include the `core` database, too.
2. The only gotchas after moving the databases should be obvious: you brought everything over from PROD so make sure to update any environment-specific settings necessary in QA.
3. Your media items should be stored in the database. You can verify by loading `showconfig.aspx` and checking the `Media.UploadAsFiles` and `Media.DisableFileMedia` settings (they should be set to `false` and `true`, respectively).
4. You should definitely get your code in QA up-to-date with what's in PROD, but you will need to make sure that it can be safely copied to QA. Does the code or configuration in PROD have anything PROD-specific. Likely there are at least connection strings that need to be adjusted, but there may be more.

Comment: Thanks Dan for listing out all the steps you'd take and addressing my questions. Marking this as the Answer for now. I'll probably be back here to comment at you after I actually get closer to trying this stuff out :D.

For one thing I'm surprised - you're really just saying to only copy `master` DB and that should be all the items? I've seen for this Prod instance, there's other DB's like Analytics, core, web too (maybe 1 other I'm forgetting).

Comment: @DonCheadle - You can certainly copy other databases, but `master` will contain all of the templates and content. If you copy the other databases you will get more than that, which you may or may not want. For example: `core` will bring security; `Analytics` will bring all the compiled visit data from xDB; `web` will bring all the published content (but that's not necessary if you perform step 6 above).

Comment: Hey Dan - can you elaborate on 1. Rebuild all content-based search indexes and 2. Rebuild the Links Databases ? I'm afraid I don't know what you're referring to, i.e. why do those things matter/what is that in Sitecore, or how to rebuild them :(

Comment: Rebuilding Sitecore indexes: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/rebuild-search-indexes.html

Comment: Rebuilding links databases: http://www.jondjones.com/learn-sitecore-cms/sitecore-content-editors-guide/how-to-rebuild-your-sitecore-link-database (note: this guide is old, but the principle is still the same: there's a link to do it in the Control Panel)

Comment: Dan - what a legend! So is that "Links" database basically what you see when you go to `Navigation -> Links` on an item in Sitecore?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Dan - when doing the publish of `sitecore/` item (right after the `master` DB has been restored by Prod), should we mark to "Publish subitems"?

Comment: Yes - that will include all the content, which you will want to update in the destination databases.

Comment: Dan - makes sense. `How will I know when that Publish of *everything* is done?` I had to log off my PC and come back to it, hence the publish progress pop-up disconnected. I don't know if it's done or not yet (its a large instance, e.g. Items table has 33k rows). Edit: is `sitecore/admin/Jobs.aspx` reliable to discover this?

Comment: Yes, `/sitecore/admin/jobs.aspx` is a reliable source, if you're not using [the Sitecore Publishing Service](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Publishing_Service.aspx).

Comment: @DonCheadle - I added a question/answer for this question, too: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/22390/342. Please have a look and let me know if it's helpful or edit it if it can be improved.

Comment: Dan I really appreciate that! That Q/A looks good to me! Only possible improvement is if you could link to relevant "official" documentation about that "/sitecore/admin" area. I only found it recently but it looks very useful...... But even better - I think it would really benefit the whole community if you weighed in on this other question that hasn't received much attention: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/22369/organize-start-source-code-from-existing-sitecore-instance