# Check publishing status after closing browser

Tags: publishing

I started a large publish job but had to close the browser before it finished. How do I check whether it's complete or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Publishing *without* Publishing Service

If you have not installed the [Sitecore Publishing Service](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Publishing_Service.aspx), then the easiest way to check is by loading the Jobs Viewer admin page at `https://your-sitecore-server/sitecore/admin/jobs.aspx`:

[image: Jobs viewer admin page]

If it is still running, it will show up in the **Running jobs** section with the progress number incrementing as you would see in the publish dialog.

## Publishing *with* Publishing Service

If you are using the [Sitecore Publishing Service](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Publishing_Service.aspx), you'll need to check the Publishing Dashboard instead at `https://your-sitecore-server/sitecore/client/Applications/Publishing/Dashboard`:

[image: Publishing dashboard]